# How I can list IPs who start all process from "USERABC"?

Tags: security, server, grep

With the commands

```
pgrep -u USERABC | xargs ps -f -p
```

or

```
top -c -u USERABC
```

we can see ALL process starteds by USERABC.

How we can see also the IPs who start this process?

By example we find:

```
USERABC 28465 25010  0 17:01 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/USERABC/public_html/forum/index.php
```

200 times.

Then we like know if this process is starteds from the same IP, or maybe 195 is from same IP
(then is a hacker surely, and we can blocked this direction!)
and others 5 from others IPs (users "legals" surely).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

grep your web server access log file for the URL.

Example:

```
grep 'forum\/index.php' /var/log/apache2/access_log
```

Comment: Thanks. This is cPanel, then logs only is saved in [/usr/local/apache/logs], but I like find {all process + IP to USERABC}, no only to the process:
"file XYZ".